# How to VOID an entire Paypal Order using REST API v2

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

> [Paypal Order REST API (V2) documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_status) defines `order.status == "VOIDED"` as a state in which "All purchase units in the order are voided"

Clearly, I can see from Docs[1](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_status) that it is possible for the `order_status` of an entire `order` to be `VOIDED`. So how exactly does one use the REST api to cancel an incomplete order i.e to proactively change the `order.status` from (let's say)  `APPROVED` to `VOIDED`?

**Note**: I am already completely aware that I can void individual authorizations of orders and make refunds on captures. I just dont know how to void an entire order (as seems to be possible). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To void an order you first have to save it and to save it order must be created with both `intent` set to `AUTHORIZE` and `processing_instruction` set to `ORDER_SAVED_EXPLICITLY`.

```
{
  "intent": "AUTHORIZE",
  "processing_instruction": "ORDER_SAVED_EXPLICITLY",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "5.00"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

After client approves order you can save it and void if needed.

**How to save order?**

Send POST request to `https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{id}/save`

**How to void order?**

Send POST request to `https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/{id}/void`.

Comment: do you have any references?